# Android 4.0.3 on mini210s ts_config: No such device

Tags: android, arm, touch-screen

Trying to install and run Android 4.0.3 on [FriendlyARM mini210s](http://www.friendlyarm.net/products/mini210s) to which I attached a 5.6inch touch screen.

FriendlyARM.ini

```
################### Android 4.0.3 ####################
Android-BootLoader = Superboot210.bin
Android-Kernel = Android/zImage
Android-CommandLine = root=/dev/mtdblock4 rootfstype=yaffs2
console=ttySAC0,115200 init=/linuxrc androidboot.console=ttySAC0 gs=0
Android-RootFs-InstallImage = Android/rootfs_android-mlc2.img
```

After installation (PASS) and reboot, I am getting this error

```
[    2.919814] s5p-tvout s5p-tvout: hpd status is cable removed
[    2.931447] Freeing init memory: 1452K
[    2.938829] yaffs: dev is 32505860 name is "mtdblock4" rw
[    2.938880] yaffs: passed flags ""
TouchDevice: /dev/touchscreen
ts_config: No such device        <=============== ERROR
[    3.218878] Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!
[    3.218964] [<c017e9c8>] (unwind_backtrace+0x0/0xf0) from [<c064ce44>]
(panic+0x70/0x1ac)
[    3.219043] [<c064ce44>] (panic+0x70/0x1ac) from [<c019aff8>]
(do_exit+0x5dc/0x68c)
[    3.219113] [<c019aff8>] (do_exit+0x5dc/0x68c) from [<c019b304>]
(do_group_exit
```

Any pointers? 
I am guessing it's something about the touchscreen config `ts_config`.